# ¿Cómo hago una búsqueda con formulario y que se muestren en otra vista? Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, formularios

estoy aprendiendo laravel creando un sistema de reservaciones en restaurantes. (Es un crud).
En este crud de reservaciones quiero implementar lo siguiente:

[image: Buscador de reservaciones por referencia]

Este buscador lo tengo en el index de una subcarpeta llamada *reservations*, la carpeta padre de esta, se llama  *restaurant* y hace referencia al restaurante en el cuál se quiere encontrar la reservación. Por poner un ejemplo:
La URL de la vista anterior sería: `http://restaurante.test/restaurant/purdy-carter/reservation`, donde *purdy-carder* es el restaurante en el que quiero encontrar mi reservación con el número de referencia.

Ahora bien, no sé cómo implementar esto... Hasta ahora, sólo he podido crear las reservaciones y mostrarlas en la vista show... Les dejo un ejemplo de cómo se muestran las reservaciones ya hechas,
Url: `http://restaurante.test/reservation/0160181cf167bf066418b9450d0fbb`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces... Cómo podría hacer la búsqueda en la vista index de 'reservation'(subcarpeta) y que me la muestre justo como me la muestra la segunda imagen, pero en el la vista 'show' de la carpeta 'reservation' (no la subcarpeta).

Por cierto, lo que "planeaba" hacer era utilizar lo siguiente, pero no sé si sea correcto.. (no sé cómo o a qué ruta mandar ese form)

```
    <x-app-layout> 
  <div class="h-full bg-gray-100 py-6 flex flex-col justify-center sm:py-12">
    <div class="relative py-3 sm:max-w-xl sm:mx-auto">
        <div class="relative px-4 py-10 bg-white mx-8 md:mx-0 shadow rounded-3xl sm:p-10">
            <div class="max-w-md mx-auto">
                <div class="flex items-center space-x-5">
                    <div
                        class="h-14 w-14 bg-yellow-200 rounded-full flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center text-yellow-500 text-2xl font-mono">
                        </div>
                    <div class="block pl-2 font-semibold text-xl self-start text-gray-700">
                        <h2 class="leading-relaxed">Busca tu reservación</h2>
                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 font-normal leading-relaxed">Rellena los siguientes datos
                            para buscar tu reservación.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    <div class="py-8 text-base leading-6 space-y-4 text-gray-700 sm:text-lg sm:leading-7">
                        <div class="flex flex-col">
                            {!! Form::open() !!}
                            {!! Form::label('reference', 'Número de referencia', ['class' => 'leading-loose']) !!}
                            {!! Form::text('reference', null, ['class' => 'px-4 py-2 border focus:ring-gray-500 focus:border-gray-900 w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none text-gray-600', 'placeholder' => 'alfo973hdnasjg4y31jd', 'required']) !!}
                            @error('client_name')
                                <p class="text-red-700">{{ $message }}</p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pt-4 flex items-center space-x-4">
                        <a href="{{route('restaurants.index')}}"
                            class="flex justify-center items-center w-full text-gray-900 px-4 py-3 rounded-md focus:outline-none">
                            <svg class="w-6 h-6 mr-3" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                    d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                            </svg> Cancelar
                        </a>
                        {!! Form::submit('Buscar reservación', ['class' => 'bg-blue-500 flex justify-center items-center w-full text-white px-4 py-3 rounded-md']) !!}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que hice fue crear una nueva función en el controlador de las reservaciones:

```
    public function obtenerReservacion(Request $request)
{
    $reservation = $request['reference'];
    return redirect()->route('reservation.show',$reservation);
}
```

Esta función se encarga únicamente de recibir valores y hacer una redirección, así que en la vista del formulario hago el envío a esta direción.

```
 {!! Form::open(['route'=> 'reservation.buscador']) !!}
```

porque así fue como la nombré en mi archivo de rutas web.php

```
Route::POST('reservation/buscador',[ReservationController::class,'obtenerReservacion'])->name('reservation.buscador');
```

Ahora si ingreso una referencia que exista me redirige a dicha referencia, de lo contrario me mandará a un 404.

También creé una vista igual a la anterior, sólo que ahora no necesita estár en ningún restaurante (por así decirlo... La url no sería: `http://restaurante.test/restaurant/{restaurante}/reservation`
sino mas bien:
`http://restaurante.test/reservation`
En donde hago prácticamente lo mismo, redirijo a la misma función etc.